# Trivial intersection of quotient subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $H/P$ and $M/P$ are two subgroups of a group $G/P$ such that intersect trivially i.e. $(H/P) \cap (M/P) = \{1_{G/P}\}$ = $\{P\}$. Is it true that $H \cap M = P?$

Comment: Do you mean $P$ and not $\{P\}$?

Comment: I assume we have $P < H < G$ and $P < M < G$?

Comment: Yes we have those subgroup relations from the correspondence theorem

Answer (score 2):

Supose

$$x\in (H\cap M)\setminus P\implies xP\neq P\;\;\text{in the quotient}\;\;G/P$$

yet

$$\;xP\in M/P\;,\;\;xP\in H/P\implies 1_{G/P}\neq xP\in H/P\cap M/P$$

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $P\subset H$ and $P\subset M$, Let $p:G\rightarrow G/P$ be the quotient map, $p^{-1}(1_{G/P})=p^{-1}(H/P\cap M/P)=p^{-1}(H/P)\cap p^{-1}(M/P)=P$. Since $H\subset p^{-1}(H/P)$ and $M\subset p^{-1}(M/P)$, we deduce that $H\cap P\subset p^{-1}(H/P)\cap p^{-1}(M/P)=P$. The result follows from the fact that $P\subset H$ and $P\subset M$.

Answer (score 0):

I know that $P\leq H\cap M$. Let $x\in H\cap M$ then $x\in H$ and $x\in M$. So we have that $xP \in H/P, M/P$ thus $xP \in H/P \cap M/P = \{P\}$. Then $xP = P$ implying $x\in P$ giving the other inclusion